# 3d integral under the limitation of norm of two vectors

Tags: integration, vectors

I would like to integrate
$$ \int d^3 \vec{k} \int d^3 \vec{q} \frac{1}{q^2} $$
under the condition that 
$$ |\vec{k}| \leq A\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ |\vec{k} + \vec{q}| \leq A$$
where $A$ is some constant.

Is this executable? I have no idea how to handle (angle term of) the second condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral is in fact analytically tractable.

Denote $|\mathbf{k}|=k$ for any vector and first consider a change of variables $\mathbf{q+k}=R\mathbf{p}$, $R^TR=1$ such that $R^T\mathbf{k}=k\mathbf{\hat{z}}$ and then regular spherical coordinates.
Then we obtain

$$\int_{|\mathbf{q}+\mathbf{k}|\leq A} d^3q\frac{1}{q^2}=\int_{p\leq A} d^3p\frac{1}{(\mathbf{p}-k\mathbf{\hat{z}})^2}=2\pi\int_0^Aq^2dq\int_{-1}^1d(\cos\theta)\frac{1}{q^2+k^2-2qk\cos\theta}\\=\frac{2\pi}{k}\int_0^Aqdq\ln\Big|\frac{q+k}{q-k}\Big|=\frac{\pi A^2}{k}\big(\ln\frac{A+k}{A-k}+1+\frac{k^2}{A^2}\ln\frac{A^2-k^2}{k^2}\Big)$$

This can be integrated once again without problem in spherical coordinates,since it depends only on the magnitude of the vector $\mathbf{k}$:

$$\int_{k\leq A}d^3k \frac{\pi A^2}{k}\big(\ln\frac{A+k}{A-k}+1+\frac{k^2}{A^2}\ln\frac{A^2-k^2}{k^2}\Big)\\=4\pi^2 A^4\int_{0}^1 xdx\Big(\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}+1+x^2\ln\frac{1-x^2}{x^2}\Big)=4\pi^2A^4(\frac{5}{6}-\frac{2}{3}\ln2)$$

I haven't checked these integrals against Alpha, so I am accepting corrections :)

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem by a way which is a little bit different of yours, and finally got $4 \pi ^2 A^4 \times (2/3 + 5/ 48 + 11/ 48) = 4 \pi ^2 A^4$. This is actually the result I was expecting, but has different coefficient from your answer (\*). However, I think this is not a big matter. The last line of your answer was really helpful because I forgot $\lim _{x \to 0} x \ln (x)$ converges to $0$. (\*) Footnote: according to WolframAlpha, at least the last equal mark of your answer leads $4 \pi ^2 A^4 \frac{5}{4}$. This is still different from my result, but perhaps it's my mistake.

Comment: Well we got the dimensions and the $2\pi$'s right, didn't we? :))))

Comment: Yes :) So I don't say things about the multiplication factor. Thank you for your sufficient and helpful answer :)

Comment: Should be
$$\int_0^A q \ln \left| \frac {q + k} {q - k} \right| \, dq =
A k + \frac {A^2 - k^2} 2 \ln \frac {A + k} {A - k}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The integral wrt $\mathbf k$ is the volume of the intersection of two balls centered at the origin and at $-\mathbf q$. The formula for the volume of a solid of revolution gives
$$V = 2 \pi \int_{q/2}^A (A^2 - x^2) dx \, [q < 2 A] =
\frac \pi {12} (q + 4 A) (q - 2 A)^2 \, [q < 2 A].$$
Then the original integral is
$$2 \pi \int_0^{2 A} \int_0^\pi V \sin \theta \, d\theta dq =
4 \pi^2 A^4.$$

Comment: Hah... I'm impressed by your beautiful answer. It seems to be an Egg of Columbus, but I'll never come up with such a solution. I just followed your calculation and got the same result. Thank you.